# MATLAB : import package for base class

Tags: matlab, import, package, directory, derived-class

i have a base class A and a derived class B which are stored in the following folder structures.

```
+myPackage (package Path)
  @A    ( folder of class A )
    A.m ( filename of class )
  @B
    B.m
```

Now i want to use class B which has the following head

```
classdef B < A
```

unfortunately this does not work because they are in different folders and i cannot import like this:

```
import myPackage.*
classdef B < A
```

Is it possible to solve this without loosing the folder organisation?

Answer (score 4):

I think if you write

```
classdef B < mypackage.A
```

it should work.

Comment: This notation brings additional problems like limit to 64 characters

Comment: As long as the package name and the class name are individually less than `namelengthmax` characters long, it should be fine. The package name and class name concatenated together can be longer than `namelengthmax`. `namelengthmax` is typically 63 characters, which I would think would be enough.

Comment: Unfornunally its not long enough. If you want to use speaking names like: domain.bestfit.forms.combinations.bundle.BrownDistortionParameters you will be hitting the limit soon. ATM MATLAB seems to have no idea how large projects are managed. Maybe MATLAB is not intended to build large applications?

Comment: Have you tried `domain.bestfit.forms.combinations.bundle.BrownDistortionParameters`?

Comment: Yes and i get a warning that the variable name will be truncated to 63 characters

Comment: `domain.bestfit.forms.combinations.bundle.BrownDistortionParameters` works fine for me. @8472 I wonder if you have something else going on. As I mentioned, as long as the packages and classes individually have less than 63 character names, the length of their concatenation should not be an issue. Although you're right that MATLAB is not as widely used for large applications as more mainstream languages such as C# or Java, there are many people out there successfully creating very complex and large-scale projects using it. Let's not blame MATLAB too eagerly!

Comment: Personally, I would suggest that 5 layers of packages is probably too many. Mathworks toolboxes routinely have 2 layers, but I can't think of any examples with more. In Java, you would generally have 3 or possibly 4. The Eclipse project (which is huge) possibly has as many as 5. I would encourage you to seriously reconsider your package hierarchy. Also, I wouldn't say that you can't use MATLAB to build large projects, because the majority of MATLAB is itself implemented in MATLAB and it's a pretty big project.

Comment: Also, this makes it difficult to change/refactor package name/organizations. Mathworks is not doing a good job as usual.