# How to correctly name and organize file classes for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, import, package, fully-qualified-naming

Consider the following directory structure and that `C:\magic` is the current MATLAB folder:

```
C:\magic
C:\magic\+wand
C:\magic\+hat
```

Now, `wand` and `hat` are MATLAB packages which may be loaded by `import wand.*` and `import hat.*`.

Consider that I may want to create an abstract class for hat inside the `+hat` folder:

```
% C:\magic\+hat\Hat.m
classdef Hat < handle
    % class implementation ...
end
```

and some child class:

```
% C:\magic\+hat\TopHat.m
classdef (Sealed) TopHat < Hat
    % class implementation
    methods
        function this = TopHat()
            this = this@Hat();
        end
    end
end
```

But when I do:

```
> import hat.*
> ha = TopHat()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using hat.TopHat
The specified superclass 'Hat' contains a parse error or cannot be found
on MATLAB's search path, possibly shadowed by another file with the same name.
```

Nevertheless, I can do `ha = Hat()` with no error.

What is possibly happening and what is the best solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: similar question: [MATLAB : import package for base class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8475312/97160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
classdef (Sealed) TopHat < hat.Hat
```

There's no "search-current-package-first"-routine in MATLAB (sorry for the bad name :>). So to refer to a class within a package you always have to carry the package name - even e.g. to refer to a static method of a class within its own classdef.

Comment: yes! I tried that soon after posing this question and it worked... I think MATLAB is quite unorganized, don't you? This issues shouldn't happen...

Comment: Compared to natively object-oriented programming languages, things sometimes seem a little artificial. But then again, OOP in MATLAB is still very uncommon - to my impression.

Comment: imo you can blame this on the import feature in Matlab... it is kind of primitive. if you think about the syntax that works, Matlab needs to understand the scope, and doesn't look in the same package etc... hopefully Mathworks will make this a bit better one day soon